# How do I download tracks from the GARMIN GPSMAP 78 usin DNRGarmin?

Tags: data, gps, download, garmin

I have been able to download waypoints to DNRGarmin by accessing the GPX file. However, I have only been able to view waypoints.

How can I download tracks?

Comment: It is unfortunate after going through the correct process the folder only lists the gpx identifier file number, date and file size and not the Track Name. It would help GARMIN users if the Track Name was the identifier rather than the file id number, particularly if multiple tracks have been saved for later transposition and use on topography maps at a later date.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. With the GPSMap 78 in particular you can no longer use the "Track" or "Waypoints" menus to download data.

The GPS is now visible as an "external" drive. So instead you have to go to File -> Menu -> Load From -> File
Navigate to the GPS and select the GPX file. (Change the File Type dropdown option to GPS Exchange Format (*.gpx) first)